# Not understanding this SQL query

Tags: sql, syntax

I'm following the Stanford's Coursera database course, and there's this query I do not understand.

The instructor says that it returns colleges paired with the highest GPA of their applicants.

```
select distinct College.cName, state, GPA
from College, Apply, Student
where College.cName = Apply.cName
  and Apply.sID = Student.sID
  and GPA >= all
          (select GPA from Student, Apply
           where Student.sID = Apply.sID
             and Apply.cName = College.cName);
```

I don't understand the `GPA >= all` part. Doesn't that mean we are looking for rows with GPA that is `>=` ALL applicants, instead of just applicants to a particular college? In other words, I think the query is returning colleges that have applicants with GPA highest everywhere.

Comment: So there is a course that teaches implicit join syntax instead of the `join` and `on` clauses, and that prefer `>= all` instead of doing an aggregation in the subquery.  No accounting for taste.

Comment: Maybe they are following Gabriel Garcia Marquez' dictum: _You must read a lot of bad poetry in order to recognize good poetry._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
College.cName = Apply.cName
```

This provides the limit to a particular college.  Try removing it.

Comment: I see. So the key idea is that `College.cName` in the subquery is referring to the `College.cName` in the outer where clause?

Comment: I guess you can say it like that.  `College.cName` is the same field for the same table, so they have the same value.  Maybe the way you said is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

No, because the select statement following the "GPA >= ALL" statement is correlated to the outer clause - they share the same table correlation names "College" "Apply" "Student". That means that you'll effectively get a a look up against the "College" currently being referenced by the WHERE clause - i.e. for College_A we look up all students within College_A, for College_B we look up all students within College_B etc.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say:

`GPA >= all` is the same with `= MAX (GPA)`: It will select only the college that have GPA `greater or equal` to all others college GPA.

Below query is the same, but easier to understand:

```
select distinct College.cName, state, GPA
from College, Apply, Student
where College.cName = Apply.cName
  and Apply.sID = Student.sID
  and GPA =
          (select MAX(GPA) from Student, Apply
           where Student.sID = Apply.sID
             and Apply.cName = College.cName);
```